# How to get the data from Google API

Tags: json, geocode

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1+acmh pennsylvania+1&key =

I can get the data by directly paste this link into my browser
but I need get many different places geocode
I tried

```
import json 
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1+acmh    pennsylvania+1&key = <YOUR KEY HERE>"
content = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
info = json.loads(content)
```

return 'Bad Request'

Comment: change `urlopen(api)` to `urlopen(url)`, then your code works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
def getGeoInfo(name):
url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s,+PA'%name)
response = requests.get(url)
geoInfo = response.json()
```

Find the solution, using direct requests.get, no need API key even!